# Cannot generate a new application wth properties

Tags: nrwl

I created an nx workspace

```
ng new nx-ng --collection=@nrwl/schematics
```

I then attempted to add an app with the following command

```
ng generate app pim --directory=ts  --tags=shared,experimental --prefix=pim --inline-style --inline-template --style=scss
```

...but I get the following error

Path "/apps/ts/pim/src/app/app.component.html" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Install the older version of angular CLI.

```
npm i -D @angular/cli@7.3.1
```

as per advice in [Closed Nx Issue#1104](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1104#issuecomment-467932316)

The default version with no generator errors when adding Nx to your project is [7.3.1](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/package.json#L30), but there a possibility that a newer version might also have a fix, e.g. upgrade to 7.3.4 etc.